# Is there any data to explore the heterozygosity of the South African lion over the last 18 years?

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, population-genetics, mammals, data

**Background**:

I need to find data on the heterozygosity of the south African lion over the last 18 years... and I'm *struggling*: so far I have found a [**single data point**](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0190369).

**Question**:

Where can I find data to help me explore changes in the heterozygosity of Lions living in South Africa?